# bash and bin/sh returning different env values in Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have a pod and a config map in my Minikube cluster.

The pod reads all env variables directly from the config map. using this syntax:

```yaml
  envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: db-config
```

Problem is: when I enter the pod using `kubectl exec -it -- bash` and enter `env` command, I see my configmap keys as expected. but when I do `kubectl exec -it -- bin/sh` and then `env`, I don't see the config-map values!

I read a few questions about difference of `bash` and `bin/sh` but couldn't find the relation with env.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; what is the exact command you're running, and what output are or aren't you seeing? You should rarely if ever need `kubectl exec`, what is the environment in the main container process?

Comment: @Amin Shojaei, I have another solution that works with both of them (tested with sh and bash). (using env => valueFrom => configMapKeyRef with volume mount). If u need it, I can explain details in the answer.